# How to make vue-HighChart responsive, but chartOptions from an API

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuetify.js

I have a little problem when I want to make my vue-highchart responsive. I have an example for it (see image 1)

[image: image 1]

---

and its mine (see image 2)
[image: image 2]

this is my code

```
<v-tab-item class="tabs__resources">
          <v-card outlined rounded="60">
            <v-container>
              <v-row>
                <v-col>
                  <highcharts :options="chart_cpu"></highcharts>
                </v-col>
                <v-col>
                  <highcharts :options="chart_memory"></highcharts>
                </v-col>
                <v-col class="py-6">
                  <v-card class="card-incoming" :ripple="false">
                    <v-layout class="py-1" align-center justify-center>
                      <v-flex>
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <h4>Incoming Rate Total</h4>
                          <h2>{{network_total.rx}}</h2>
                        </div>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                  </v-card>
                  <v-card class="card-outgoing" :ripple="false">
                    <v-layout class="py-1" align-center justify-center>
                      <v-flex>
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <h4>Incoming Rate Total</h4>
                          <h2>{{network_total.tx}}</h2>
                        </div>
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                  </v-card>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-container>
          </v-card>
        </v-tab-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chose responsive.rules to fit the charts, manipulate size and center to change position of pie. Plot chart area is reserved for the whole circle, you need to remember this when you setting.

```
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 400
      },
      chartOptions: {
        series: [{
          size: '100%',
          center: ['50%', '50%'],
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5kh9ad4w/1/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive